# IPhone: Does my app need to support multitasking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

Is this now a mandatory requirement before uploading to the app-store? As I understand it, making my app compatible with multitasking is something extra that I need to implement. (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mandatory to support multitasking.

To disable multitasking, you can use the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key in your info.plist file, which may appear as "Application does not run in background."

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html for more information.

Answer (score 5):

No.

It's not something extra. It's an opt-out process. Read [this Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW24).

My personal opinions is that if you don't actively support multi-tasking, you should opt-out from it.

Comment: For what it's worth, in my opinion you should support fast app switching, even if you don't support anything else. As users become accustomed to switching to recently-launched apps with fast switching, it will seem weird and less-functional if yours isn't there and the user has to hunt it down again in springboard.

Comment: That's not the case. You can check by yourself, but a program is added to "recently-launched app" independent of whether or not it supports multi-tasking. That's not a list of apps staying in the background. As far as an app launch fast enough, you don't see a difference. Of course Apple won't make that kind of artificial distinction :)

Answer (score 2):

Your app does not need to take advantage of the multitasking features, but it DOES need to gracefully handle being put in the background and never receiving a notice that the application will quit. More specifically:

Under previous versions of the OS when the user quit the app (by pressing the home button) the App Delegate's

```
applicationWillTerminate
```

was called. Under iOS 4 pressing the device's home button instead puts the app in the background, calling the App Delegate's

```
applicationDidEnterBackground
```

When the app is brought to the foreground again the OS call's the App Delegate's

```
applicationWillEnterForeground
```

This most commonly caused trouble for older apps when state changes -- user preferences, data files, high scores, etc. -- were being written out and saved when *applicationWillTerminate* was called. Now that it's no longer being called, some apps fail to save user information.

Most anything that you were doing when *applicationWillTerminate* was called should now also be placed in *applicationDidEnterBackground*, depending on what your app does.

Additionally, it's possible that some things you were doing in *application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* will also need to be done in *applicationWillEnterForeground*, depending on what your app does.