# IPhone: Why does my app resume and not restart when I relaunch it on device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I don't know if this is an iOS4 thing or something, but basically say I have a few screens in my app. Now, when I hit the home button and relaunch my app it launches the app on the screen where I left off. It's almost like it's not restarting my app, but resumes it. I don't want it to do that. (I'd like it to show my splash screen main menu, etc. )

Does anyone know how to resolve this? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 4, apps are suspended (not terminated) when the home button is pressed. When you "relaunch" the app, it is simply moved to the foreground. If you want your app to terminate when the user presses the home button, set the value of `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in your app's `Info.plist` file. If you do this, when the user taps the home button the `applicationWillTerminate:` method of your app delegate will be called and then your application will terminate.

Comment: note that I just went to my .plist file in xcode, double clicked it and then added the property "Application does not run in background" and checked it. I think behind the scenes it's called "uiapplicationexitsonsuspend" so i'll give you the benefit of the doubt. ehehe.

Comment: Good point; the plist editor can show user friendly key names. If you right click on your plist and select "Show Raw Keys/Values" you'll get a peek behind the curtain. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you. Basically what you need to do is disable the multi-tasking features of iOS4.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/60989-disable-multi-tasking-ios4-application.html

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the multi-tasking you asked about yesterday working behind the scenes. You need to opt-out if you want that behavior. See answers to your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860939/iphone-does-my-app-need-to-support-multitasking). Have you read the answers there???

Comment: haha, you're good. yes, I read your answer that's why in this question I said "i think it's an ios4 thing" because i remembered what you said about multitasking. i guess i just didn't know for sure if multitasking meant resuming...