# iOS Application is not resuming where it left off?

Tags: ios, background, resume

I am facing the above issue and unsure why it is happening or how to fix it. When the app goes to the background and is later reopened, it always starts from the initial view.

I would like it to show the view that was shown when the app was dismissed - which is usually the default for iOS apps.

Can someone please explain why this might be happening and how I can resolve it.

Comment: In addition to the answers, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868848/iphone-why-does-my-app-resume-and-not-restart-when-i-relaunch-it-on-device). It probably helps to search stack overflow with some keywords before asking a question. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is probably killed while in the background to free it's resources for other tasks.

If applicable you can opt to use a background mode for your app so it keeps running in the background. This is possible if you require location updates, play audio or interact with bluetooth le devices.

By your description it's more likely you want to implement [State preservation and Restoration (Programmig Guide)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html)

> Even if your app supports background execution, it cannot run forever. At some point, the system might need to terminate your app to free up memory for the current foreground app. However, the user should never have to care if an app is already running or was terminated. 
> [...]
>   The state preservation system in UIKit provides a simple but flexible infrastructure for preserving and restoring the state of your app’s view controllers and views.

Comment: i understand that, but i am killing my app . i am playing a stream in background so that means it running and if then i comes back issue is there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on an iPhone older that the **3GS**, this is normal. Apps are closed instead of backgrounded on these older models.

The other possible reason is that you've set
`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend=YES`
in your Info.plist. In that case, your app will also always terminate when going to the background.

Comment: No, I am using iphone , i have tried this "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" not working this meant for something else.Thank You for reply.

Comment: which model of the iPhone are you using?

Comment: i am using , iPod 4th Gen, Iphone 4 , iPhone 4S,iOS sdk 6.0 sim

Comment: about the background music. you have set "Requirement background modes" to "App plays audio"?

Comment: If that is the case and the music keeps playing when the app comes back to the foreground, it must be something that you did programmatically in `viewDidAppear` or `applicationWillEnterForeground`